# How to access JSON array object in HTML using angular?

Tags: html, arrays, json, angularjs

I have a JSON file and I want to display it in my HTML. But I dont know how to use the syntax for deeply nested objects.

```
  {
  "questions": [
    {
      "question": "Qw1",
      "answers": [
        {
          "answers": "An1",
          "value": 25
        },
        {
          "answers": "An2",
          "value": 50
        },
        {
          "answers": "An3",
          "value": 75
        },
        {
          "answers": "An4",
          "value": 100
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "question": "Qw2",
      "answers": [
        {
          "answers": "An1",
          "value": 25
        },
        {
          "answers": "An2",
          "value": 50
        },
        {
          "answers": "An3",
          "value": 75
        },
        {
          "answers": "An4",
          "value": 100
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not trying to use ng-repeat, as I need to access them them one by one.

```
 <div class="main-content" ng-controller="QuestionCtrl">
                <div id="Content1">
                  <h1>Question 1</h1>
                  <p>{{questions.question[1].answer}}</p>
                  ...........
```

Ofcourse it doesn't work. How do I acces my information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Awc2LbO9NL1gYrhiipyY?p=preview)

Using this controller:

```
.controller('QuestionCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) { 
  $scope.questions = [];
  $http
    .get("data.json")
    .then(function(response){
      $scope.questions = response.data.questions;
    });
}])
```

which is loading your data, we can use this

```
<div class="main-content" ng-controller="QuestionCtrl">
  <div id="Content1">
  <h1>Question 1</h1>
  <p>{{questions[0].question}}</p>
  <p>{{questions[0].answers[0]}}</p>
  <p>{{questions[0].answers[1]}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or we can use it like this:

```
<h1>Question 1</h1>
<p>{{questions[0].question}}</p>
<h2>answer 1</h2>
<p>{{questions[0].answers[0].value}}</p>
<p>{{questions[0].answers[0].answers}}</p>
<h2>answer 2</h2>
<p>{{questions[0].answers[1].value}}</p>
<p>{{questions[0].answers[1].answers}}</p>
```

which will show the numeric `value` and `answers` **text**

Check it [here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/Awc2LbO9NL1gYrhiipyY?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But instead of **{"answers":"An1","value":25}** how can I fetch just their value?

Comment: I updated the plunker *(reopen that plunker)* and also the answer. that should show you how to. We can simply access the answers[0].answers to get text and answer[0].value to get the number... good luck

Comment: Tnx! I know this has been an easy one xD

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="main-content" *ngFor="let q of questions">
   <h1> {{q.question}}</h1>
    <p *ngFor="let ans of q.answers">{{ans.answers}} = {{ans.value}} </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`questions` is the array, not `questions.question`, and your JSON does not contain `answer` properties. Did you try using the correct traversal?

```
questions[0].answers[0].value
```

should get you `25`.